# GNOME Suspend restarts the machine

Tags: gnome, suspend, debian-bullseye

Occasionally (say once in a week, 3-5 suspends in a day) "Suspend" restarts the computer. Just silently goes to restart.

Is that restart fixable? Is there a system command which explicitly does what GNOME does when 'Suspend' menu is selected?

At first I thought it was my mistake (the 'Restart...' is the next menu item to 'Suspend'), then I double checked several times that I really invoke 'Suspend'. Besides, 'Restart...' if were called should show the dialog. The problem is old (couple of months at least). The recent restart happened at 2022-11-29

Using GNOME 3.38.5, Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye), AMD A6-5400K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics

All updates are installed as soon as they available.

**UPDATE 2022-12-31**

GNOME Power Off/Log Out > Power Off... also restarts the machine (made sure to uncheck 'Install updates'). Do not use "Power Off" much, can't say if a restart is always the case.

**UPDATE 2023-01-01**

Following Daniel B advice I did the best (what my quite restricted knowledge of Linux logs, how crash looks like or the normal reboot, allowed me) to analyze the system (/var/log ) log files. It is the pure guess because I found none of the logs which for me looked exactly like crash. The lines which were suspicious for me is the following:

```
Dec 31 20:26:40 ambler gnome-shell[1553]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.


Dec 31 20:33:57 ambler kernel: [    0.042630] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x100000000-0x100000fff]

Dec 31 20:33:57 ambler kernel: [    0.046800] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-20-amd64 root=UUID=a1a2c748-336b-43b9-bf1d-6201827ea52d ro quiet
```

They are from:

```
$ sudo dmesg -T -F /var/log/messages.1
```

Comment: It’s highly likely it does not _restart_ but crash. Check the logs to see whether it actually shut down and then restarted or not.

Comment: @DanielB it is terra incognita for me. I did the best I could to analyze logs. The city turned power supply off. I hurried to shutdown the machine. Instead of shutdown it went to restart. Had to analyze log when the power supply was restored which happened noticeable later. I will update the OP